# titlte/tooltip reaction on boolean change HTML, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how can you use 2 different tooltip titles for either true or false...
I' am stuck at moment with

```
title="{'text1' : attribute===true , 'text2' : attribute===false}"
```

This doesn't seem to be the correct approach...A little help from you guys would be nice. thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
title="{{ attribute ? 'text1' : 'text2'}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use AngularJS ternary operator:

```
title="{{ attribute ? 'text1' : 'text2' }}"
```

If `attribute` is `true`, then `text1` else `text2`.

Comment: 10 seconds faster! ;)

Comment: Works great thank u, by the way, how would it react on undefined if you use this expression. Would it show nothing? regards and +1

Comment: @AlexW ok, I changed `condition` with `attribute` to match your case.

Answer (score 1):

A ternary operator will do the trick.

```
title="{{ attribute ? 'text1' : 'text2' }}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use a question mark as a minimal if()

```
title="{{attribute?'text1':'text2'}}
```

This is the simplest way in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ternary operator.

```
title="{{ attribute ? 'text1' : 'text2' }}";
```